# Two fields in a table related to another table

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to do a query in MS Access (which is like going back in time 20 years) and cannot work out how to do alias tables so that two columns in my base table lookup values from another table expecting to get two different corresponding results from the join.

I have two tables - stations and routes. I want to create a query which results in route id, origin and destination which gives me the station name for both.

stations (station_id, station_name)

1,"Auckland"

2,"Wellington"

3,"Hamilton"

routes (route_id, station_from_id, station_to_id)

1,1,2

2,1,3

3,2,3

4,3,2

5,3,1

6,2,3

result from query should be

1, Auckland, Wellington

2, Auckland, Hamilton

3, Wellington, Hamilton

4, Hamilton, Wellington

5, Hamilton, Auckland

6, Wellington, Hamilton

SELECT a.station_id AS station_from, b.station_id AS station_to

FROM routes

INNER JOIN stations ON stations.station_id = routes.station_from_id AS a

INNER JOIN stations ON stations.station_id = routes.station_to_id AS b

That's all I need it to do, but in access, no idea how to make it work, query wizard produces the weirdest results that I can't work with.

Thanks for your help with this, kind regards, Matt

Comment: Sample data and the output you're trying to obtain from that data would be helpful.

Comment: fair point, I'll have to do that from work as the access file is on that laptop. Basically, I have two fields in one table related to an ID in another table. the ID is for a train station. In table1 I have station_from and station_to, both with _id. When I create a query, there is two JOINs, one from > station and one to > station. I expect in the query results two values, the station name of from and to, thanks

Comment: how do you add an attachment? cannot find anywhere either as an edit nor comment option

Comment: You can't add an attachment. You can post sample data in text format, and do the same with the desired results. See this [Meta StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139013/172661) for a relatively easy way to get it formatted properly for pasting here.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, I've added as an edit, thanks

Comment: Your sample data and latest query don't match your question text or output description. Your text describes three tables, and mentions `zones` and `zone_pricing`, neither of which are in your sample data or output. The text also describes wanting *station_code for both station_from and station_to
price which is looked up from zone_id in zone_pricing table*, and neither your sample tables or query text includes `zone_id` or a `zone_pricing` table. When you're asked to provide sample data and output to your post, that data should match the question text so we know exactly what you're asking.

Comment: apologies @KenWhite I created a new database which specifically deals with the problem I have, namely, an alias query in MS Access. The other parts of the query I can do, I'm only stuck on retrieving results from two joins relating to the same table. If I retrieve the data from zones, zone routes and stations it would be too much to paste in this thread. Thanks

Comment: That's fine, but edit your original text to match what you're now asking. I've got an answer ready to post for you, but can't post it until you correct the question or I'll end up being downvoted because my answer does not match your text and people won't see your requirements changed in the comments. Correct your question, and I'll post my answer.

Comment: thanks @KenWhite I've corrected the question :)

Comment: And I've posted my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly threw this together to produce the output you want.

```
select 
  r.route_id, o.station_name as Origin, d.station_name as Destination
from 
  ((routes r
inner join 
  stations o on o.station_id = r.station_from_id)
inner join 
  stations d on d.station_id = r.station_to_id)
```

The results:

```
route_id   Origin          Destination           
--------   ------------    ------------------
       1   Auckland        Wellington               
       2   Auckland        Hamilton                 
       3   Wellington      Hamilton                 
       4   Hamilton        Wellington               
       5   Hamilton        Auckland                 
       6   Wellington      Hamilton
```

Comment: thanks for this, it apparently has a missing operator on query expression. I changed route_from and route_to to station_from and station_to to match my test db but it's just erroring - it looks right, can't work it out - its MS365 Access

Comment: This query works fine in Access, and uses nothing but standard SQL syntax. I have no idea what you changed to make it fail, but I tested this and copied/pasted the output from it into this answer. I just copied it back out, pasted it, and ran it again and got the same output. The SQL I posted here is correct, so you've apparently introduced an error with your changes. I can't see them from here.

Comment: the field names were station_from and station_to so I replaced route_to and route_from for that.

Comment: I just changed the field names in routes to route_to and route_from and used exactly the pasted version but nadda :(

Comment: You changed the wrong columns, then. As I said, my version is working exactly as written. The `stations` table has two columns (station_id and station_name), and the `routes` table has three (route_id, route_from, route_to). Changing those to match your column names should be very straightforward.

Comment: Change my `route_from` to your `station_from_id` and my `route_to` to your `station_to_id`. No other changes should be needed or made. I've adjusted my answer to use your **exact** column names.

Comment: thanks @kenwhite, I changed it, the query looks absolutely perfect, even tried it on a different database, must be something wrong with this test db - I will make it work, I know what you've done is correct - you've been a star, thank you

Comment: ah, Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join. I got it to work

Comment: SELECT
  r.route_id,
  o.Station_Name as Origin,
  d.Station_Name as Destination
FROM
 ((routes r
  INNER JOIN stations o ON o.station_ID = r.route_from)
  INNER JOIN stations d ON d.station_ID = r.route_to);